# gradle cannot find generatedDensities property

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to only generate `mdpi` and `hdpi` drawables for a certain apk I have, but when I try to build the app i get this error:

```
* Where:
Script '/Users/myuserID/app/build.gradle' line: 40

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> No such property: generatedDensities for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor_Decorated

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

the code in the build file looks like this:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId “com.myproject.box"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName “6.0"
    **generatedDensities = ['mdpi', 'hdpi']**
}
```

and in the top level `build.gradle` file i have the following defined:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
}
```

`generatedDensities` is suppose to tell gradle to only create `mdpi` and `hdpi` drawables, why is it not recognized? As soon as i remove the `generatedDensities` the app builds as usual.

You can refer to [here](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/vectors-for-all-almost/) for any further clarification on the property.

Comment: What is the version of the Android plugin for Gradle that you are using? This would be in your top-level `build.gradle` file, in your project root directory.

Comment: i updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get that error because `generatedDensities` was added in Android Plugin for Gradle v1.4.0 as stated by the  `ProductFlavor` [documentation](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/1.4/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.html). As you can see `generatedDensities` is not available in the [v1.3 documentation](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/1.3/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.html).

Change your `build.gradle` to this:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0-beta6'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
}
```

Comment: how did you come up with this ? can you tell me where to look next time so i can see when it was added ? It looks like you just looked here right ? http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/1.4/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.html

Comment: @j2emanue I just updated my answer with a references to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Update your classpath to 1.5

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that since gradle:2.0.0-alphaXX `generatedDensities` is deprecated.
Use `vectorDrawables.generatedDensities` instead.

```
defaultConfig {
   ...
    //generate drawables from vectors
    vectorDrawables.generatedDensities= ['mdpi','hdpi']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar thing:

```
vectorDrawables.generatedDensities = [ 'ldpi', 'mdpi', 'hdpi', 'xhdpi', 'xxhdpi', 'xxxhdpi']
```

But it is not overtaken to the apk. But the files are generated in the directory `\generated\res\pngs\google\debug` ... whereas in the `apk` the directories have names like "`drawable-mdpi-v4`" ...

Now. I copy the PNG's manually to the app. At least I didn't have to convert them manually :-|